# How to send custom url from jenkins to email?

Tags: jenkins

I need to send my report url in content to mail from jenkins after build in editable email notification. Can any one please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Please configure the editable email notification build steps as below :

**Project Recipient List**: someone@example.com,anyone@example.com
(**NOTE**: This is a comma-separated list of email addresses that should receive emails)

**Project Reply-To List**: replyto@example.com,plsreplyto@example.com (**NOTE**: This is a comma-separated list of email addresses that should receive emails)

**Content Type**: HTML (text/html)

**Default Subject**: This is subject of email

**Default Content**: (**NOTE:** here you can write HTML Code to add links and other elements) below is the example

```
<b>Build Status: </b>$BUILD_STATUS <br><br>
<b>Console Output of Build #$BUILD_NUMBER : </b> <br>
<span style="display:block; padding: 3px 10px; border-radius: 5px;white-space: pre"> 
$BUILD_LOG
</span>
<br>
<b>Build URL : </b>$BUILD_URL<br>
<b>Report URL :</b> https://myreport_url.com
```

Now, click on **Advance Settings**
In "**Triggers**"

**Triggers**: click "Add Trigger", select the condition when you want to trigger the email based on build status. for example, if you want to trigger an email for all the builds then select "**Always**"

Now, remove the "***Developers***" from "**Sent To**" (In the same trigger configuration as shown below)
[image: Tigger_IMG]

In the same configuration, ensure below configuration

**Recipient List** should be empty

**Reply-To List** : $PROJECT_DEFAULT_REPLYTO

**Content Type** : Select Project Content Type

**Subject** : $PROJECT_DEFAULT_SUBJECT

**Content** : $PROJECT_DEFAULT_CONTENT

You can always click (?) next to each field to understand its role and what values it expects.